# Moving a value after php returns the table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a title on my page. It is inside a div tag. When the page is displayed it is simple and says "Net Control Manager". After the user makes a selection a PHP program runs MySQL and returns a table. It also returns a value that I want to put into the title. So that it would say "Net Control Manager: PCARG" for example.

The problem is I'm not sure how to put that extra piece into the div. I write the value to another div with an echo from the php "echo $value" which is returned correctly. Then in an onload in the body tag I use a function to retrieve the new div (newport), and add it to the title div. But since the onload happens first all I get is "undefined".

How do I make it wait for the new div to be written with the new data? Or is there another method I don't know about.

Comment: Can you show some code and be more specific please? If you already put the result in a div, why don't you put it directly in the div you want (the title one)?

Comment: You can use Jquery Ajax and send a request to the server and after populating your table in success call back function modify your element title

Answer (score 1):

If I read this correctly, you're just looking to pick up some text and append it to another div's text?

You could do something like this -- making sure it's at the bottom of your HTML before the closing `</body>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var title = $('#title'); // Or whatever your div id or class name is.
    var newport = $('#newport'); // Or whatever your div id or class name is.

    // This will append the text from your `newport` onto your `title` div. 
    title.text(title.text() + ' ' + newport.text())
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This is the concept I was looking for. And in fact what I was doing in a piece of javascript already but in the head tag. So I copied your code and put it just above the </body> tag as you suggested. I also put an alert in it so i could tell when and if it ran. It never executes. How do I get it to execute?

Comment: I changed the type= to text/javascript and now the function does execute but like before it runs before the value it needs is returned by php. The function needs to wait for the newport div to be populated.

Comment: Ok, Edited my answer to fix my <script> tag :)

Comment: Without seeing your full codebase it's really hard to tell what's going on. Is the newport div being populated via an AJAX call after the DOM is loaded?

Comment: Thanks for the input Tyler Kelley it still not working. A slightly off topic issue question deals with your request to see the "full codebase". I'm happy to have you take a look at the code I just don't know how to share it. Do I just put a link to my entire project here, or do you need just the index.php? I pretty new at using stack overflow for support. Maybe a quick example would help.  P.S. I completely understand the logic of your code, it just doesn't do anything... my misunderstanding of something no doubt.

Comment: Usually you can just paste some of the offending bits of code into gist.github.com and paste the link here, or create a reproduceable case on something like jsbin.com. But since this is (seemingly) full stack question, those two options probably won't work super great. 

At the very least if you can drop the offending HTML\jQuery onto a Gist, that would be a good start.

Comment: The site is https://net-control.us. Using the drop down select one. Notice that the title at the top of the page says 'Net Control Manager' also notice that under the table, in the lower left corner it has a call sign WA0QFJ for example. My goal is to put the call sign next to the title at the top of the page.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So what you'll want to do is trigger the code I posted above when the user clicks on one of these dropdown items. This may be a bit more involved than a simple copy and paste into the document body.

Comment: What you'll want to do is find the onClick event that is tied to those drop down items, look for the AJAX handler that is making the call to the server to get that data, and add the code to change the title in there.